# Tensor product of irreducible representation of $\mathfrak{sl_3}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let $\omega_1$ and $\omega_1$ be fundatmentl weights and $V(\lambda)$ be the unique irreducible representations of highest weight $\lambda$ of $\mathfrak{sl_3}$.

I want to decompose, for $m>n$,
$V(m\omega_1) \otimes V(n\omega_2)$.

I have been given the hint to consider symmetric powers of 'the obvious modules'. I know that $Sym^a(V(\omega_i))=V(a\omega_i)$ but I am not sure how to employ that here as I am not sure how symmetric powers interact with the tensor product.

Comment: @hm2020 I believe they are saying they have already got $S^a\Gamma_{1,0} = \Gamma_{a,0}$ and are now trying to prove $\Gamma_{a,0} \otimes \Gamma_{0,b} = \Gamma_{a,b} \oplus \Gamma_{a-1,b-1} \oplus \cdots \oplus \Gamma_{a-b,0}$ for $a>b$ which I believe is the formula in this case

Comment: What Callum said is correct. The proof of the formula I have written comes from noting that indeed the LHS has the the correct highest weight vector and comparing dimensions. I am unsure on how to get a  Clebsch-Gordan for sl3. I am aware of the rule for sl2

Comment: @Callum do you have a hint on how to prove that formula?

Comment: the sl2 proof kinda works by counting weights but thats easy bc for sl2 reps weights have dimension 1, here i think things get a bit more tricky

Comment: As an example: There is a natural map $Sym^2(V) \otimes \wedge^2 V \cong Sym^2(V) \otimes V^* \rightarrow V$. What is the kernel of this map?

Comment: @RickSmith - there is a dimension formula for $dim(\Gamma_{(a,b)})$ and you may check that the representation $\Gamma_{(2,1)}$ has dimension $15$. You get an exact sequence $0 \rightarrow \Gamma_{(2,1)} \rightarrow Sym^2(V) \otimes V^* \rightarrow V \rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question:** "I want to decompose, for $m>n$,  $V(m\omega_1) \otimes V(n\omega_2)$. I have been given the hint to consider symmetric powers of 'the obvious modules'. I know that $Sym^a(V(\omega_i))=V(a\omega_i)$ but I am not sure how to employ that here as I am not sure how symmetric powers interact with the tensor product."

**Comment:** Let $\Gamma_{(a,b)} \subseteq Sym^a(V) \otimes Sym^b(\wedge^2 V)$ be the irreducible module on $SL_3$ corresponding to $\lambda:=(a,b)$ for $a,b \geq 0$. It follows  $\Gamma_{(0,1)}:=\wedge^2 V$ where $V$ is the "standard representation" of $SL_3$.

You may find this in the Fulton/Harris book:

There is a canonical contraction map

$$i_{a,b}: Sym^a(V) \otimes Sym^b(\wedge^2 V) \rightarrow Sym^{a-1}(V) \otimes Sym^{b-1}(\wedge^2 V)$$

with kernel $\Gamma_{(a,b)}$. Hence there is a direct sum decomposition

$$Sym^a(V) \otimes Sym^b(\wedge^2 V) \cong \Gamma_{(a,b)} \oplus Sym^{a-1}(V) \otimes Sym^{b-1}(\wedge^2 V).$$

**Example:** In the case of the map from the comments: There is a canonical surjective map

$$i_{2,1}:Sym^2(V) \otimes V^* \rightarrow V$$

defined by

$$i_{2,1}(uv \otimes f):=f(u)v+f(v)u.$$

The kernel $\Gamma_{(2,1)}$ has highest weight vector $e_1^2 \otimes (e_1 \wedge e_2)= e_1^2 \otimes x_3$.

In the book they prove the following general formula:

$$dim(\Gamma_{(a,b)}) = \frac{(a+b+2)(a+1)(b+1)}{2}$$

and this formula implies there is an exact sequence of $SL_3$-modules

$$(*)0 \rightarrow \Gamma_{(a,b)} \rightarrow Sym^a(V) \otimes Sym^b(\wedge^2 V) \rightarrow Sym^{a-1}(V) \otimes Sym^{b-1}(\wedge^2 V) \rightarrow 0 .$$

When you count the dimensions in $(*)$ you get the following:

$$\binom{a+2}{2}\binom{b+2}{2}-\binom{a+1}{2}\binom{b+1}{2}=$$

$$\frac{(a+1)(b+1)}{4}((a+2)(b+2)-ab)= $$

$$\frac{(a+b+2)(a+1)(b+1)}{2} = dim(\Gamma_{(a,b})$$

hence the sequence $(*)$ above is exact (this is exercise 15.19 in the mentioned book).

**Question:** "How does this apply directly to solve my question? –  RickSmith"

**Answer:** Since $SL_3$ is semi simple it follows any short exact sequence of representations split hence there is by $(*)$ an isomorphism

$$Sym^a(V) \otimes Sym^b(\wedge^2 V) \cong \Gamma_{(a,b)} \oplus Sym^{a-1}(V) \otimes Sym^{b-1}(\wedge^2 V).$$

Your formula follows using an induction.

Comment: How does this apply directly to solve my question?

Comment: Thanks! I am wondering how does the canonical contraction imply the direct sum decomposition? I.e. How do we know the exact sequence splits?

Comment: @RickSmith - this is a general property of $SL_3$: if $G$ is a "semi simple" linear algebraic group and if $V$ is any finite dimensional representation, there is a "canonical" direct sum decomposition $V \cong \oplus_i V(\lambda_i)$ (as representations) where $V(\lambda_i)$ are irreducible representations. This property implies the above sequence has a section.

Comment: @hm2020 That is not quite true. There is a canonical decomposition into isotypic components (components comprising direct sums of a single irreducible rep) but those components can be divided up into irreducibles in various ways.

Comment: @Callum - "canonical" mean you may "permute" the irreducible components. If $W \cong V_1 \oplus V_2$ is the decomposition of $W$ into irreducibles, we may also write $W \cong V_2 \oplus V_1$. I assume this is what you are speaking about.

Comment: ..hence if $V_1,..,V_k$ are the irreducible components of $W$ and $ \sigma \in S_k$ is a permutation, you may write $W \cong V_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus V_k \cong V_{\sigma(1)} \oplus \cdots \oplus V_{\sigma(k)}$. I believe it is "common practice" to refer to these two decompositions  as "the canonical decomposition" into irreducibles.

Comment: @hm2020 no that's not what I mean. If you have repeated copies of the same irreducible rep you can split the direct sum of the repeated copies (which is called an isotopic component) up into a direct sum in infinitely many ways. Consider, for example, $\mathbb{C}^2 \oplus \mathbb{C}^2$ as a $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-rep can also be split up into diagonal and "anti-diagonal" parts i.e. the set of all $(x,x)$ and the set of all $(x,-x)$ respectively. These are also subreps.